# connection refused from server unit I reset client machine

Tags: python, tcp, client

Below is the code I am running within a service. For the most part the script runs fine for days/weeks until the script hiccups and crashes. I am not so worried about the crashing part as I can resolve the cause from the error logs an patch appropriately. The issue I am facing is that sometimes when the service restarts and tries to connect to the server again, it gets a `(10061, 'Connection refused')` error, so that the service is unable to start up again. The bizarre part is that there is no python processes running when connections are being refused. IE no process with image name "pythonw.exe" or "pythonservice.exe." It should be noted that I am unable to connect to the server with any other machine as well until I reset computer which runs the client script. The client machine is running python 2.7 on a windows server 2003 OS. It should also be noted that the server is coded on a piece of hardware of which I do not have access to the code.

```
try:            
        EthernetConfig = ConfigParser()
        EthernetConfig.read('Ethernet.conf')

        HOST = EthernetConfig.get("TCP_SERVER", "HOST").strip()
        PORT = EthernetConfig.getint("TCP_SERVER", "PORT")

        lp = LineParser()
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        s.connect((HOST, PORT))
        reader = s.makefile("rb")

        while(self.run == True):

            line = reader.readline()
            if line:
                line = line.strip()
                lp.parse(line)
except:

        servicemanager.LogErrorMsg(traceback.format_exc()) # if error print it to event log
        s.shutdown(2)
        s.close()
        os._exit(-1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Network Admin had the port closed that I was trying to connect to. It is open for one IP which belongs to the server. Problem is that the server has two network cards with two separate IP's. Issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Connection refused is an error meaning that the program on the other side of the connection is not accepting your connection attempt. Most probably it hasn't noticed you crashing, and hasn't closed its connection.

What you can do is simply sleep a little while (30-60 seconds) and try again, and do this in a loop and hope the other end notices that the connection in broken so it can accept new connections again.

Comment: +1 A delay is a good idea, I will give that a try. However it still does not explain why even with no python process's open I still cannot connect to the server. Even after some time.

Comment: @Richard: No it's the server that refuses the connection, there is nothing wrong on your end.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I realize that the server refuses the connection. Reading the documentation it allows only 2 connections at one time. what I don't understand is that when I reset the client machine, I am able to connect to the server again, which is making me believe that there is something using up the connections on the client machine, although I have no proof that it indeed the case.